# Using rails 4, how to deeply nest resources in a parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Writing a recipe app.  Having a hell of a time getting this down.

My Models:

**Recipe**

- has_many :recipe_ingredients
- has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

**Recipe_Ingredient**

- belongs_to :recipe
- belongs_to :ingredient

**Ingredient**

- has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
- has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

**My routes are simple**

resources :recipes // AND A FEW RANDOM OTHERS

In my Recipes Controller:

```
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    recipe_ingredients = @recipe.recipe_ingredient.build
    recipe_ingredients.ingredient.build
end
```

My Recipe Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @recipe do |r| %>

<%= r.input :title, label: 'Recipe Name:' %>
<%= r.input :description, label: 'Recipe Description' %>

<%= r.simple_fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ri| %>
  <%= ri.input :quantity, label: "Quantity" %>
  <%= ri.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
      <%= i.input :name, label: "name" %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %> 
<%= r.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  The error is:

```
undefined method `recipe_ingredient' for #<Recipe:0x000001034d3650>
```

any ideas?  Spent 2 nights on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular error seems to come from referencing `@recipe.recipe_ingredient` (singular), which should be pluralized, since it is a `has_many` relation. Try this in your `RecipeController#new`:

```
recipe_ingredients = @recipe.recipe_ingredients.build
```

Then, for the `recipe_ingredients.ingredient`, try using `build_association` instead:

```
recipe_ingredients.build_ingredient
```

Comment: I see your point, I updated and it spits out: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass on .ingredient.  If I pluralize ingredient(s) then I get an undefined method ingredients.

Comment: For a `belongs_to` association, try using `build_association` instead of `build`. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks for the notes @Drenmi. That did work.  the correct line was: recipe_ingredients.build_ingredient